# How to detect in JavaScript when any link or submit button is clicked on a webpage

Tags: javascript, http

I have a web page that shows remote asset data (for example weather station data) and that does background XMLHttpRequest()'s every 5 seconds to our server and reloads the page if new data from the remote asset has been received. This has all been working fine for years.

The page also has numerous links and submit buttons that can be used to go to other pages or submit commands to the server (which then sends a command to the asset). Issue I'm having is that some of the commands the server then executes involve calls to 3rd party web services, some of which can occasionally take up to 30 seconds to return or time out. But in the meantime if new data came in from the asset the background JS function reloads the page, thereby interrupting and cancelling the new http request that the user initiated.

I could probably work around this by adding onclick or onsubmit tags to every link and submit button to call a function to disable the timer, but as there can be dozens of links on the page I am hoping there might be a simpler, more elegant way where one simple function can tell me if the user clicked on something and thereby initiated a new active http session.

I enable my script by doing a `setTimeout('myCheckServerFunction("'+url+'")',5000);` from the html head. If the server then tells it there is new data it does a `setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},5000);`

So I'd like to disable the JS timer and prevent any reload if the user has clicked any link or button and thus if a new http session is active. Does there exist a function like this? eg. something like "window.isNewHttpRequestActive()" ?  Or maybe there's a way I can check if the window.location changed? (not sure if that would get updated before the new http request is complete.)

Otherwise I could maybe attach a addEventListener() to every link and submit button on the page but I'm a PHP dev not JS so if anyone could recommend the best way to parse the DOM and attach a listener to every link and submit button that would work too.

I did try looking for events that "bubble" up to higher layers eg. the body element and that will catch link clicks but also catches any click even just a click on any blank area, So not sure how well that would work as I'd still need to filter that event to determine if it actually came from a link or button. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Listening to all click events on body isn't necessarily a bad idea.

EDIT: As gre_gor pointed out in comment, it might be. The perceived target of the click is not always the link or button if other elements are inside of them.

So my original method, which was using `event.target.tagName` is to be avoided.

The following code would add an event listener for `click` on every `a` element of the document, and let you cancel the timer if it is set :

```
for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName("a") {
    element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (relocationTimeout !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(relocationTimeout);
            relocationTimeout = undefined;
        }
    });
}
```

Up to you to adapt the selector in the loop to fit your needs.

Of course don't forget to store the timeout reference in a variable when you set it :

```
let relocationTimeout = setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},5000)
```

Comment: If you click on another element inside those, this won't work. e.g. `<a href="#"><span>text</span></a>`.

Comment: This was helpful as a starting point for some testing, however it does not work well for buttons, as those come through as an event from an 'input' element and getElementsByTagName() does not seem to be able to differentiate between different input types such as a text box vs. a submit button.  So if someone clicks in a text box I get an event, but I only want to know if someone clicks something that actually results in an http request. Thank you

Comment: This might be on the long and convoluted side of things in terms of instructions but replacing `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` with `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).filter(element => element.type === "/*input type here*/")` would let you specify the type of input tag you want.

But at this point it might be better to manually give a specific class to every element that needs to be checked and rather use that.

Comment: You could still listen to all click events. You would just need to travel up the DOM tree to check, if the event was bubbled up to `a`/`button`/`input[type=submit]`. Or just do `event.target.matches("a, a *, button, button *, input[type=submit]")`.

Comment: @gre_gor the event.target.matches is helpful as it does make it possible to now catch all clicks on links and buttons. Only downside is I have some <a> tags with no href (inactive links) so I still get an event if I click on one of those even though they don't initiate an http request.  As a temporary solution what I'm now doing is getting the events with document.body.addEventListener() to get all click and submit events (called from body onload), then if target.matches as you described I then just reset my timer to 45 seconds. That gives enough time for any new http request to complete. ...

Comment: (continued) so this meets my needs for now but I am still amazed there does not exist anywhere in JS an API function to check if there is an active http request!  Still hoping someone knows a way to do that as it seems like a basic fundamental thing that JS ought to be able to do.